# Inherit editText from Theme.Light with Holo parent theme

Tags: android, inheritance, android-theme

I want to inherit the `editText` from `android:Theme` while my parent theme is `android:Theme.Holo.Light`.
Is there any "clean" way to do this short of copying the resources from the android sdk folder into my project?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So my idea would be to have a custom theme (really just a style) that extends from `android:Theme.Holo.Light`, and then overwrites the `EditText` attributes to use the parent settings from `android:Theme`.

It looks like `android:Theme.Holo.Light` uses an `editTextStyle` attribute reference to change the appearance of the `EditTexts`:

```
<item name="editTextStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.EditText</item>
```

So you can override it with the `editTextStyle` from `android:Theme`:

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@android:style/Widget.EditText</item>
</style>
```

Then, all you have to do is apply `YourTheme` in your manifest (or in code if you really want to) to get your custom theme. You may want to tweak stuff further, check out all the stock themes here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

### Edit

I just tested this out and realized that it appears that `android:style/Widget.EditText` doesn't seem to apply the background from older versions of android, most likely because it uses a reference to `android:editTextBackground`, which `Holo.Light` sets. I just tried also changing `android:editTextBackground` manually to the legacy `EditText` drawable, and it works for me.

*Note: Only apply this adjustment on your `styles.xml` under `/values-v11`, since only version 3.0 and can use `android:editTextBackground`, and older versions of android will already use the old `EditText` background. If the app min is >= API 11, you don't need to worry about this.*

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@android:style/Widget.EditText</item>
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@android:drawable/edit_text</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That looks like what I'm looking for! Should I write `<item name="android:editTextStyle">@android:style/Widget.EditText</item>`? Just "editTextStyle" gives me an error, saying that no attribute can be found.

Comment: @beenjaminnn yes you are spot on, I forgot to add the namespace, and Android will look for the attribute in your app otherwise (and not find it). See my update, as my original answer didn't completely solve the problem.

Comment: Perfect, this solved my problem! I hate the holo and material edittext

Answer (score 0):

Yes you create a styles.xml and set the style parent to whatever you want. :-)

Example of how to define a style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
            <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
            <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
            <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

Use this style like so:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

Read more about it here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#DefiningStyles

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I understand that I can create my own customized editText style that way, but I want to just inherit the older android theme's editText. Do I do something like this?

    `<style name="editTextStyle" parent="@android:Theme.Light:style/editTextStyle">
        </style>`