# Change style for edittext in android

Tags: android

I want to change style for edittext. I use :

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etRange"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:hint="wprowadź adres"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light"/>
```

but this solution changes nothing. How can I change style only for edit text on holo light?

Comment: what are you trying to change the style to?

Comment: I need to change this style because when I use DialogFragment my edittext from white change style on black rectangle. When  I use Dialog I don't have this problem

Comment: How about style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Widget.EditText"

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17347017/419449